# How can I use Bearer Token to secure a Jakarta REST API with Jakarta Security's @OpenIdAuthenticationMechanismDefinition?

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, openid-connect, jakarta-ee-security-api

With the WildFly server and the integrated OIDC auth-method it is possible to secure a jakarta ee 10 rest api just sending a Bearer token in the Authentication Header. I have just to config it like this in the web.xml file:

```
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>OIDC</auth-method>
    </login-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>secured</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

With a oidc.json file and no additional rest-filters (add serverside) it is possible to use for example Bearer tokens which I receive from a keycloak server in the rest client api which is calling this rest server here.

But with the new OpenIdAuthenticationMechanism (@OpenIdAuthenticationMechanismDefinition), which was introduced with jakarta security 3 (jakarta ee 10) it is not possible for me to get it running the same way because if I call the rest api with the Bearer token like before the application is redirecting me to the keycloak server.
My question is: Is it possible to teach the new mechanism to use the token from the Authorization header, or is that not intended?

No more code to provide.